# matching URL to a pattern using php

Tags: php

I have to use crawlers for my project.

I've used simple dom class to get all the links from a page.

Now I want to filter only those links which are of the form `"/questions/3904482/<title of the question"`.

Here's my attempt:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest');
$pat='#^/question/([0-9]+)/#';
foreach($html->find('a') as $link)
{
    echo preg_match($pat, $link->href);
    {
        echo $link->href."<br>";
    }
}
```

All the links get filtered out.

Comment: you say the url is question**s** but your pattern shows no s

Comment: @user2969918 Have my answer worked for you? :)

Answer (score 1):

you say the url is question**s** but your pattern shows no s

Also, it looks like you should be using `if` not `echo`

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest');
$pat='#^/questions/([0-9]+)/#';
foreach($html->find('a') as $link)
{

    if ( preg_match($pat, $link->href) )
    {
        echo $link->href."<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of DOM and XPath:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$questions = $xpath->query("//a[contains(@href, '/questions/') and not(contains(@href, '/tagged/')) and not(contains(@href, '/ask'))]");

foreach ($questions as $question) {
    print "{$question->getAttribute('href')} => {$question->nodeValue}";
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but if the `@` operator is used, the value of `$dom` perhaps ought to be checked `:)`.

Comment: Yeah, I've used it here just to suppress `loadHTMLFile()` output warnings (for non well-formed files). Another way to do that is calling `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` just before. :)